# strange behavior of std::cout in c++

Tags: c++, expression, std, operator-precedence, expression-evaluation

```
#include <iostream>

int a(int &x) {
    x = -1;
    return x;
}

int main () {
    int x = 5;
    std::cout << a(x) << " " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Why output is "-1 5"?

PS: compiler is:

i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

PS: compiled without any optimization.

Comment: The standard term for these is function side effects

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this line:

```
std::cout << a(x) << " " << x << std::endl;
```

the order of evaluation of `a(x)` and `x` is not specified. It's unspecified behaviour what happens, in your case the compiler decided to evaluate `x` first, `a(x)` afterwards.

Comment: It is *undefined behavior*? I think it is *unspecified behavior*.

Comment: @Nawaz Hm, could be unspecified behaviour (§1.3.15) I think. Edited.

Comment: This is strange in my opinion because function has worked already. And i hoped that value in the cell in a memory was changed. Maybe somebody can explain me how it can be translate in an asm code?

Comment: @SukhanovNiсkolay It is changed, if you look at it *after* this line. The compiler turned this line into `auto tmp1 = x; auto tmp2 = a(x); std::cout << tmp2 << " " << tmp1 << std::endl;` (without the additional sequence points, of course) - which is legal although, as already mentioned, not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

The order, in which `a(x)` and `x` are being evaluated is ***unspecified*** <sup>[1]</sup>. To make sure that `x` will not be modified within the same expression (and avoiding unspecified behavior by doing so), you could do:

```
int x = 5;
int y = a(x);
std::cout << y << " " << x << std::endl;
```

---

[1] *"Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands of individual operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the order in which side effects take place, is unspecified. "* <sub>***5 Expressions, §4***</sub>

Comment: I think it is *unspecified*, not *undefined*.

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation is unsequenced and hence it is [unspecified behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) either `a(x)` or `x` could be evaluated first. With respect to the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `1.9` *Program execution* paragraph *15* says(*emphasis mine*):

> [...]**Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced**. [ Note: In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the execution of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced evaluations of its subexpressions need not be performed consistently in different evaluations. —end note ] [...]

and it may even differ between different evaluations and furthmore if we go back to paragraph *13* it says:

> [...]**If A is not sequenced before B and B is not sequenced before A, then A and B are unsequenced**. [ Note: The execution of unsequenced evaluations can overlap. —end note ] Evaluations **A and B are indeterminately sequenced** when either A is sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A, but **it is unspecified which**.[...]

which explains that this is unspecified behavior.